# Checkbox not updating value knockout js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, knockout.js, observable, computed-observable

I'm new at knockout js and feel I may not be understanding something here. I basically have a MVC checkbox, that when checked will update another field which is dependent on other field calculations. I can get the total amount field to update with respect to all of the other fields except for the checkbox, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I suspect that it's because I'm not passing in a `self`, but I'm not sure how I would pass that in with the conditional value in the final equation, but I'm not sure why that would be the case at all either. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

I also noticed that if I made the calculations into variables and returned the final variable, the initial value would show correctly, but then nothing would make the final field update. Is there a reason this is the case or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Here is the checkbox markup I'm using

```
<div class="form-group-sm">
    <label for="bookingType">International Property</label>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInternationalProperty, new { @id = "internationalProperty", @value = true, @data_bind = "checked: internationalProperty" })
        <label style="width: 200px; text-align: left">Select if it is outside the US</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my knockoutjs view model

```
var viewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.internationalProperty = ko.observable();
    self.vendorBookingAmount = ko.observable(2.00);
    self.transactionFeesDue = ko.observable(0.00);
    self.transactionFeesWaived = ko.observable(0.00);
    self.iceBookingFees = ko.observable(0.00);
    self.vacationCashRedeemed = ko.observable(0.00);
    self.pointsDiscount = ko.observable(0.00);
    debugger;
    var international = (self.internationalProperty() == true) ? 0.05 : 0;

    self.memberBalance = ko.computed(function () {
        return (Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
            Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
            Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount())) +

            (Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
            Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
            Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount()))*international;
    }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the calculation of `international` variable inside of the memberBalance. Right now you are calculating it only once, and then memberBalance is using the same `international` value

```
    self.memberBalance = ko.computed(function () {
        var international = (self.internationalProperty() == true) ? 0.05 : 0;
        return (Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
            Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
            Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount())) +

            (Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
            Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
            Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount()))*international;
    }, self);
```

EDIT: 
If you view source and look at your generated HTML, you will see that `data-bind` statement is just not there for the checkbox. The issue is that `@Html.EditorFor` has different parameters from `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, `@Html.TextBoxFor` etc.

See post: http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/

The syntax you need to use is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInternationalProperty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "internationalProperty", @value = true, @data_bind = "checked: internationalProperty" } })
```

Note the wrapper object with htmlAttributes property.

Comment: hmmm, it still doesn't seem to work. @Voyta, was there any update bindings that I need to include? I know that for the textboxes I put `, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'`, maybe there is a similar binding for checkboxes?

Comment: It worked! Not sure if I would have figured that out, thanks!